# GDB - How to break on "something is written to cout"?

Tags: c++, gdb

I would like to set a breakpoint that triggers every time something is written to `stdout` via the `cout` stream, but I'm having trouble finding a possible position for this breakpoint.

How can I do this in gdb?

Comment: There is an answer to the similar question here: "break before a certain string is written to std:cerr": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956727/gdb-break-before-a-certain-string-is-written-to-stdcerr/11982234#11982234

Comment: As far as I can see, the technique in the linked question is similar, but will only break if a `string` is written to `cout`. To use this to break on any write to `cout`, one would have to set a breakpoint for every overload of `operator<<`. (and there are tons of them)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a platform dependent way. If you are on x86_64 and building with gcc writing to std::cout results in calling `fwrite`. Backtrace looks like this:

```
#0  0x0000003c2fc622a0 in fwrite () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003c43289655 in std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x0000003c432898c7 in std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x0000003c43291e5c in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

So this is a possible way to break on writing to std::cout (std::cout is http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_1.1.0/gLSB/baselib--io-2-1-stdout--.html):

```
b fwrite if $rcx==&_IO_2_1_stdout_
```

And this is a way to break on writing to std::cerr (std::cerr is http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_1.0.0/gLSB/baselib--io-2-1-stderr--.html):

```
b fwrite if $rcx==&_IO_2_1_stderr_
```

Answer (score 7):

simply use rbreak as follows:

```
gdb> rbreak std::ostream::operator<<
```

you can write every regular expression which matches your function name. This is the easiest way to catch all template instances for example. If the regex I wrote in the example is not strong enough, feel free to write a more specialized one. I hope that I could provide a start point.

Comment: yes, it will maybe. Op asks for cout not for write. gdb should be able to catch also inlined functionality so a cout which was optimized to fwrite should also be catched.

Comment: `rbreak` seems like a super-useful command to know, however in this case it is slightly too broad because it will also catch writes to all other types of `ostream`'s (like `stringstream`'s)